# "Preview" mpdf directly to browser

Tags: php, mpdf

I'm using mpdf and writing a bunch of HTML to the pdf object via mpdf::writeHTML().  Is there any way, rather than outputting an PDF, to simply dump it right back to the browser instead?  So, rather than creating the PDF just write it out as a web page?

I want to give the user the option of a PDF or a web page, and rather than branching off for echo or writeHTML for each line, I'd like to build the document and then either output web or PDF.

EDIT TO ADD:

Something like this:

```
$mpdf = new mpdf();
$mpdf->writeHTML( "<p>Hello World</p>" );
$mpdf->addPage( 'L' );
$mpdf->writeHTML( "<p>Lorem ipsum egg foo yung.</p>" );

if( $_GET['format'] == 'pdf' ) {
    $mpdf->output();                  //spit out a PDF
} elseif ( $_GET['format'] == 'web' ) {
    echo $mpdf->contents_as_html();   // write a web page
}
```

I'm currently writing each line to a giant string, and then either passing the string to mpdf::writeHTML() or echo; but this doesn't allow me to use various mpdf functions such as addPage(), bookmark(), and so forth.

Comment: can't you just put everything into one variable like `$output .= 'line of html';` and then at the end do a single `writeHTML($output);` or `echo $output`?

Comment: That’s kind of what I’m doing now, but it precludes any sort of non-HTML within the document, such as mpdf bookmarks

Comment: you really need to add your code then so we can see what your doing

Comment: Added some example code, but don't get too hung up on the precise specifics. The question is, on general principle, can I somehow output whatever has been added via $pdf->writeHTML() to a web page instead of a PDF?

Comment: Extend the class and overwrite the method, and have it append the passed HTML code to a new class property (string or array), so that you can simply request the whole thing from there in the end ...? If you need to take stuff like addPage into account too somehow when creating your HTML, overwrite that as well.

Comment: Interesting idea, @CBroe . It involves duplicating data already being stored somewhere else in the object, but as I haven't been able to decipher where exactly it's currently stored, this may be a way to go!  (For unrelated reasons, I've already extended the mpdf class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did, per a suggestion by @CBroe.  When `writeHTML()` is called, it writes to an internal variable `$this->strHTML`, and then does its normal process.  If the object is cast to string, it returns `$this->strHTML`

```
class myPDF extends Mpdf {

    private $strHtml = '';

    public function writeHTML( $html, $mode = 0, $init = true, $close = true ) {
        $this->strHtml .= $html . "\n";
        return parent::writeHTML( $html, $mode, $init, $close );
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->strHtml;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can choose the output with mPDF by changing the second parameter.

```
I = send the file inline to the browser.
F enter code here= save to a local file with the name given by $filename.
S = return the document as a string. $filename is ignored.
D = send to the browser and force a file download with the name given by $filename.
```

Output mPDF:

```
$mpdf->Output($filename, "I"); // Change "I" to your preferred output
```

If you choose output the file in your browser, just make sure that you target the output on an empty page. Otherwise it's possible that the header and footer will interfere.

Artikel mPDF output:
https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/output.html

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all